# Google search algorithm and SERP

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, pagerank, google-ranking

Why would google rank some pages of a website in the top 2 positions, and not rank at all the other pages and some in between? If Google's algorithm follows strict rules and guidelines, then won't all the pages be considered the same? with those pages being having the same structure.

Comment: ya, i forgot to delete that one, i edited the question to better suit the website's policies. now deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Google ranks content based on relevance to the user's query, not in a vacuum.

So while it could theoretically be possible that many pages have similar "ranking power" due to similar structure and number of backlinks, etc., only one of those pages will have the most relevant content for a specific query, and so will show up on top of the others.